# groovy/SoapUi Call a static function from another script

Tags: methods, groovy, soapui

I am trying to write a groovy script which will contain functions that are common to the SoapUI test Suite. Specifically I want to write a script that will contain all the logs that are output from the test suite.

GroovyScript1 will call a function in the GroovyScripts.groovy file. All is present in a SoapUI test suite.

I have not found any helpful advice on how to perform this task.

To specify again, I want to call a function contained in another Groovy Script.

Comment: Not exactly. But this will does that provided put all the reusable methods in a groovy class like `class GroovyScripts { // all your reusable methods goes here}`. Compile this class and create a jar file and place this file under SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory. Now whereever is required, just call the mothods from above class in Groovy script test step in any of your projects. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes You can do this by following steps,

In your "GroovyScripts.groovy" file add below code,

```
class GLF
{

    def log
    def context
    def testRunner

    def GLF(logIn, contextIn, testRunnerIn)
    {
        this.log = logIn
        this.context = contextIn
        this.testRunner = testRunnerIn
    }

    //Till abobe line you must keep same code except class name 

    public String returnVal()
    {
        return 'Himanshu'
    }
}

context.setProperty("Rt", new GLF(log, context, testRunner))
============================ END GroovyScripts.groovy ==========
```

Now in your "GroovyScript1" file you should use below code,

```
lib = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["GroovyLibraryFunction"].testCases["TestCase 1"].testSteps["EndpointVerification"]

lib.run(testRunner, context)

def RT = context.Rt

def PT = RT.returnVal()

log.info PT
```

This way you can achive your target.